# Why isn't the button report showing?

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason when I run this I can't get the alert to pop up when I hit the buttons

```
<head>
    <title>OnMouseOver Demo</title>
```

My Script

```
function buttonReport(buttonId, buttonName, ButtonValue) {
    //information about the id of the button
    var userMessage1 = "Button id: " + buttonId + "/n";
    //then about the button name
    var userMessage2 = "Button name: " + buttonName + "/n";
    //and the button value
    var userMessage 3 = "Button value: " + buttonValue;
    // alert the user   
    alert(userMessage1 + userMessage2 + userMessage3);
}
```

In the body I have this

```
<input type="button" id="id1" name="Left Hand Button" value="Left" 
onclick = "buttonReport (this.id, this.name, this.value)"/>
<input type="button" id="id2" name="Center Button" value="Center" 
onclick = "buttonReport (this.id, this.name, this.value)"/>
<input type="button" id="id3" name="Right Hand Button" value="Right" 
onclick = "buttonReport (this.id, this.name, this.value)"/>
```

Comment: Have you some errors in console ? (firebug, or developer tools for chrome)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

If this is really your code, then

```
var userMessage 3 = "Button value: " + buttonValue;
```

is a syntax error. There should not be a space before the `3`.

Comment: Also, ButtonValue and buttonValue mismatch. (buttonValue is undefined)

Comment: Yep, that too. OP - it's always a good idea to have the developer console open while working on a page or code for a page.

Comment: I did that and it did not help.

Comment: @user2905092 have you checked the developer console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

User @Pointy was right on the first part.

If this is really your code, then

```
var userMessage 3 = "Button value: " + buttonValue;
```

is a syntax error. There should not be a space before the 3.
Blockquote

Also I used ButtonValue in the function arguments/parameters
then button value without the uppercase b in the actual function